# Adding new columns to df.pivot_table

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, indexing, pivot-table, financial

I'm looking at some financial time series data, and am having trouble adding a new column to a pivot table that I created using a dataFrame. The original data frame is called **df** and has the following format.

```
            Factor       DlyReturn
DataDate        
1996-12-31  BETA       -1.447831e-03
1996-12-31  MOMENTUM   -0.000090
1996-12-31  SIZE       -2.030551e-03
1997-01-01  BETA       -3.546312e-07
1997-01-01  MOMENTUM    0.000012
1997-01-01  SIZE       -6.264164e-08
1997-01-02  BETA       -1.789611e-03
1997-01-02  MOMENTUM   -0.003170
1997-01-02  SIZE       -2.353855e-04
1997-01-03  BETA        1.729851e-03
1997-01-03  MOMENTUM   -0.000198
1997-01-03  SIZE        1.179356e-03
1997-01-06  BETA        6.946758e-04
1997-01-06  MOMENTUM    0.000812
1997-01-06  SIZE        1.956925e-04
```

df is indexed by the column "DataDate". I went ahead and created a pivot table that would give me the values in "DlyReturn" first by indexed by "Factor" and then indexed by "DataDate"using the following

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Factor',df.index],values='DlyReturn')
```

the new object **pivot** now has the following format :

```
Factor          DataDate  
BETA            1996-12-31   -0.000383
                1997-01-01   -0.000010
                1997-01-02   -0.003319
                1997-01-03   -0.000467
                1997-01-06    0.001267
```

I'm now trying to add a column to this pivot table that gives me the rolling standard deviation for BETA, MOMENTUM, and SIZE across the entire date range contained in "DataDate". I made the following attempt but kept getting an error

```
pivot['rolling_std']=pd.rolling_std(pivot.xs(('Factor','DataDate'),axis=0),window=252)
```

The error message i kept getting KeyError: ('Factor', 'DataDate'). Can't figure out if there's a mistake in my code, or if stylistically I'm approaching this all wrong. Hoping someone will have some suggestion.

Comment: Does this return inaccurate values: `pivot['rolling_std'] = pd.rolling_std(pivot,window=252)`?

Comment: Hi, that still throws back an error, `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

Comment: Can you post more of your data for several days across `Beta`, `Momentum`, and `Size`?

Comment: No errors here. Try converting your pivot_table result into a dataframe type: `pivot = pd.DataFrame(pivot)`.